# php read line by line and retrieving data

Tags: php

I have a list(data1.php) which contains data like below:

```
06/26/2015,33.51718,-81.71856,0.0,4001,15:39:57,39256,1,0.0,13.6,
06/26/2015,33.51721,-81.71858,0.0,4001,15:40:57,39256,1,0.0,13.7,
06/26/2015,33.51720,-81.71860,0.0,4001,15:41:57,39256,1,0.0,13.6,
06/26/2015,33.51719,-81.71858,0.0,4001,15:42:58,39256,1,0.0,13.7,
06/26/2015,33.51720,-81.71860,0.0,4001,15:43:58,39256,1,0.0,13.6,
```

I am trying to retrieve only the 2nd and 3rd data(lat and long). The out put file has results like below:

```
Lat:33.51718
Long:-81.71856
Lat:33.51720
Long:-81.71860
Lat:33.51720
Long:-81.71860
```

It is skipping every other line. Here is my code. Please help.

```
<?php
    $fn = fopen("data1.php",'r') or die("fail to open file");
    $fp = fopen('output.php', 'w') or die('fail to open output file');
    while($row = fgets($fn)) {
      echo fgets($fn). "<br";
      $num = explode(",", $row);

      $lat = $num[1];
      $long =  $num[2];
       echo "<p>Lat: {$lat}</p>";
      echo "<p>Long: {$long}</p>";

      fwrite($fp, "Lat:$lat\n");
      fwrite($fp, "Long:$long\n");

    }
    fclose($fn);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
 while($row = fgets($fn)) {
echo fgets($fn). "<br";
```

You read 1 line from the file and immediately after that you read and echo another line without actually processing it. Remove the echo and you should be fine

Comment: For even more fun, switch your `fgets` and `explode` to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Or `echo "$row<br>";`

Comment: Ohhhh :-) Thank You very much Danny!

Comment: Hi Josh, Thank You! Appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<?php
$fn = fopen("data1.php",'r') or die("fail to open file");

$fp = fopen('output.php', 'w') or die('fail to open output file');

$stop = "0";

while($row = fgets($fn)) {


$num = explode(",", $row);


$lat = $num[1];
$long =  $num[2];
if($stop == "1" or $stop == "2"){

echo "<p>Lat: {$lat}</p>";
echo "<p>Long: {$long}</p>";

fwrite($fp, "Lat:$lat\n");
fwrite($fp, "Long:$long\n");
}else{}

$stop++;
   }
fclose($fn);
fclose($fp);

  ?>
```

Comment: Thank You Mohammed! I appreciate that!